# How to add css class when scrolling down page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add css display:unset when scroll down and height = 400 ;

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-warning fixed-top navbar-transparent" color-on-scroll="400"  style="display: none;">
</nav>
```

I use this to get hieght

```
const height = $(window).height();
const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
console.log(scrollTop);
```

Comment: Could you please include what you have tried? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to listen for the scroll event and then calculate how much height has been scrolled. After that, when the scrolled height meets 400 add your css. The sample code is as follows,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>= 400){           
        $('.navbar.navbar-expand-lg').css('display','unset');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code with demo. Please have a look.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 400)
    $('nav').addClass('nav-color');
  else
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-color');
});
```

```css
.nav-color {background: #ff0000; position:fixed; top:0;left:0;right:0; padding:15px; z-index:1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-warning fixed-top navbar-transparent">Test
</nav>
<img src="http://photo.akmall.com/editor/goods_desc/71/90/06/14/71900614/20150502210521_K146976_BLE_1.jpg" />
```